# how to access a spreadsheets with python

Tags: python, spreadsheet, telepot

so, I found this  [google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fkCwu0zeX1BBGcNEzWGZDr2kQ0IOPSoZQK2FD-zpw1M/htmlview?sle=true#)  and i really want to use it in combination with a telegram (TELEPOT) bot, to receive information of the weapon with a query given by the user, like:

```
elif text.startswith('/wiki'):
    bot.sendChatAction(msg_data['chat_id'],action='typing')
                item = text[6:]
                bot.sendMessage(msg_data['chat_id'],'https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/'+item)
```

The spreadsheet Is not mine, And I have no idea how to access the json file with credentials

Comment: Have you seen the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)?

Comment: yeah, but, can i do this with a spreadsheet that is not mine ?